# How can I connect dynamically created actions

Tags: c++, qt

Following the answer [In Qt 4.7, how can a pop-up menu be added to a QToolbar button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364957/in-qt-4-7-how-can-a-pop-up-menu-be-added-to-a-qtoolbar-button) I can create menus on the fly, but how can I connect these menus in a way that I recognize which menu was used?

If I create these menus in a loop, I have to connect all of them to same slot

For example when I have a button and I create menus for it:

```
button
-menu 1
-menu 2
```

Using code similar to this

```
    int r=0;
    while (r<2)
    {
        QAction *action = new QAction("menu " + QString::number(r), this);
        Menus->addAction(action);
        // here I could use connect in order to connect this menu to a certain slot
        // but that would make all of them trigger the same function
        r++;
    }
    ui->Button->setMenu(Menus);
```

How do I recognize if menu I activated was menu 1 or menu 2? Is it possible to create a slot which has pointer to sender object so that I can for example, read the text?

Comment: Seems that QObject::sender is what I need :o

Comment: see [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html)