# I created a QToolButton and the label would include "..." but it looks like Qt removes them, is that right?

Tags: qt, menu, qmenu, qtoolbutton

I use the following code, the first part, creating the QToolButton, is from Designer/moc, the rest I added.

```
// Moc part
QToolButton * f_tool_button = new QToolButton(bottom_grid);
f_tool_button->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("f_tool_button"));
f_tool_button->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow",
                                               "Tool Button...", 0));

// What I added
f_action = new QAction(this);
f_action->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("f_action"));
f_action->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow",
                                          "&Click...", 0));

f_menu.reset(new QMenu("Tool Button Menu ...", this));
f_menu->addAction(f_action);

f_tool_button->setDefaultAction(f_menu->menuAction());
```

If I don't call `setDefaultAction()`, the title appears as expected.

When I add the default action, the label seems to be replaced by the `f_menu` title, **"Tool Button Menu ..."** (I put a somewhat different label on purpose). But somehow the "..." gets removed from the name.

Any idea about this problem? Is that a special Qt feature?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but are you directy editing the h-file generated by moc? Since those are automatically generated all changes will be lost the next time you run moc.

Comment: No, I'm adding my code in my MainWindow constructor implementation. It's to show all the pertinent code in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QToolButton` displays text from `QAction`'s [`iconText` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#iconText-prop) (not [`text`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#text-prop)). `text` is meant to be used in menu entries, whereas `iconText` is meant to be displayed in tool bars. When not set, `iconText` is a stripped version of `text`.

To override the default behavior of stipping `text` to generate `iconText`, you can set the desired `iconText` for your `QAction` using `QAction::setIconText()` (i.e. `f_action->setIconText("Click...");` right after your `f_action->setText` call).

Comment: The problem I have is in the `f_menu`, I guess I wasn't clear in my question which one has missing the `...`. The `QAction` text works as expected.

Comment: However, doing a `f_tool_button->setText("Click...");` just after the `setDefaultAction()` works!

Comment: @AlexisWilke, I think that you just meant to write `f_tool_button->setDefaultAction(f_menu->actions().at(0));` instead of the last line in your code snippet. `menuAction` is the action for the whole menu, and you seem to be looking for the `action` that you have just added using `addAction`...

Comment: No I really want the extra little button to the right with the drop down extra selection. That gives me two options on the same button.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, Oh, I misunderstood you because I don't usually add `QMenu`s to `QToolBar`s the way you are doing it. I usually do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5365184/2666212). Anyway, If your concern is the 3 dots at the end of "Tool Button Menu...", You just need to set `iconText` (as indicated in my answer) on your `menuAction()` before setting it as the default action for the `QToolButton` (i.e. `f_menu->menuAction()->setIconText(f_menu->menuAction()->text());`). Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Yes! That works! And it's certainly cleaner than my previous `setText()` after the `setDefaultAction()`.